# Xcode 9 crashes when opening any xib (or storyboard)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xib, xcode9

Xcode crashes when I open an XIB. Same issue across different projects. I restarted my computer, deleted derived data and still crashing. How to fix?

Comment: Have you had a look at the crash log?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try opening any storyboard. Afterwards you can open any xib in your project. Its an Xcode 9 bug.

Comment: No idea why this is badly rated, saved my day!

Comment: Nice catch. it help me too. What has happened to Apple. Missing you steve jobs :)

Comment: And one more day saved!

Comment: @QadirHussain, nothing unusual. There were a lot of similar problems in the times of iOS 3.x. Looks like we (developers) are the last Apple's priority - I think its because of the time (lack of the time).

Comment: In my case, the Main.storyboard was crashing as well. I had to open the LaunchScreen.storyboard to finally get back everything to work

Comment: LaunchScreen.xib works too

Comment: Working for me too in XCode 10 also

Comment: You can also delete your derived data then reopen the project